# Return a number from String after a specific word

Tags: c#, .net, regex, substring

I want to get a Substring out of a `String`.

The Substring I want is a sequence of numerical characters.

**Input**

```
"abcdefKD-0815xyz42ghijk";
"dag4ah424KD-42ab333k";
"BeverlyHills90210KD-433Nokia3310";
```

Generally it could be any String, but they all have one thing in common:

- There is a part that starts with KD-
- and ends with a number
- Everything after the number to be gone.

In the examples above this number would be `0815`, `42`, `433` respectively. But it could be any number

Right now I have a Substring that contains all numerical characters after KD- but I would like to have only the 0815ish part of the string.

**What i have so far**

```
String toMakeSub = "abcdef21KD-0815xyz429569468949489694694689ghijk";
toMakeSub = toMakeSub.Substring(toMakeSub.IndexOf("KD-") + "KD-".Length);
String result = Regex.Replace(toMakeSub, "[^0-9]", "");
```

The Result is `0815429569468949489694694689` but I want only the `0815` (it could be any length though so cutting after four digits is not possible).

Comment: Sounds like you should use regular expression not just to replace but to match and extract.

Answer (score 4):

Its as easy as the following pattern

```
(?<=KD-)\d+
```

**The way to read this**

`(?<=subpattern)` : *Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion. Continues matching only if subpattern matches on the left*.

`\d` : *Matches any decimal digit.*

`+` : *Matches previous element one or more times.*

**Example**

```
var input = "abcdef21KD-0815xyz429569468949489694694689ghijk";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=KD-)\d+");
var match = regex.Match(input);

if (match.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}

input = "abcdef21KD-0815xyz429569468949489694694689ghijk, KD-234dsfsdfdsf";

// or to match multiple times
var matches = regex.Matches(input);

foreach (var matchValue in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(matchValue);
}
```

Comment: omg thank you. It worked! And sorry for bothering you I am new to regex.